# How to redirect the user from the route defined with Id when the user is not login In Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I am working in my login/register system. I have defined the route with the id and when the user is not login and try to visit that route, it will redirect to login page and when the user is login then he can visit that route but the problem is that when the user is trying to visit that route with the id, it is showing the error.

This is my **tabs.router.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';
import { AuthenticationGuard } from '../guards/authentication.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2/:id',
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab4',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../login/login.module#LoginPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

In this `tab2` is with id.

This is my **authentication.guard.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private storage: Storage, public alertController: AlertController) {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    let isLoggedIn = false;
    this.storage.get('ID').then((val) => {
      if (val) {
        isLoggedIn = true;
        return true;
      } else {
        this.presentAlertConfirm();
        return false;
      }
    });
    return true;
  }

  async presentAlertConfirm() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      message: 'Please Login To Participate In The Challenge',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab4']);
          }
        }]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
}
```

In the guard, when the user is not login, it will redirect to the login page.

But the problem is when I try to visit the `tab2` page, it is showing the error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab4']);` to `AuthGuard` if you want to redirect after error. Currently you navigate to `/tabs/tab4` in Cancel button click handle.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private _router: Router,
  ) {}
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return this.storage.get('ID').then((val) => {
      if (val) {
        isLoggedIn = true;
        resolve(true)
      } else {
        // Place your redirect here:
        this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab4']);
        this.presentAlertConfirm();
        resolve(false);
      }
    })
  }

async presentAlertConfirm() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      message: 'Please Login To Participate In The Challenge',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            resolve(true)
          }
        }]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try resolving the Promise on your auth guard. My guess is that right now you're choosing to return a boolean, but you're using a storage service that requires a promise, so you're not waiting for the promise chain to finish executing.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private _router: Router,
  ) {}
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return this.storage.get('ID').then((val) => {
      if (val) {
        isLoggedIn = true;
        resolve(true)
      } else {
        this.presentAlertConfirm();
      }
    })
  }

async presentAlertConfirm() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      message: 'Please Login To Participate In The Challenge',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            resolve(true)
            this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab4']);
          }
        }]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
}
```

Comment: When the user is not login and try to visit path: 'tab2/:id', it wont show the error.

Comment: If you could create a repro in StackBlitz, I can investigate and update my answer to fix the issue.

Comment: I just want that when the user visit the 'tab2/:id and it is not login, it will redirect to some other page.